# Display different content based on Boolean

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to allow only manager to create view a content on my website, So I added an entry to my model `Profile`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

By default is false

If false the user cannot see the content.

So I tried :

```
{% if profile == manager %}
    SHOW THE CONTENT
{% else %}
    Does not show the content
{% endif %}
```

But nothing change.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried doing `if profile.manager`

Comment: I tried, but is not working either

Comment: Please add your view code

Comment: I have nothing relevant to this problem on my view so I added my full models.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like that :

```
  {% if user.profile.manager %}
    SHOW THE CONTENT
{%else%}
    Does not show the content
{% endif %}
```

You forgot to add user since it is connected

Answer (score 0):

You added a property on your model.

Your `Profile` object won't == manager. You need to access the property on your `Profile` object.

Try

```
{% if profile.manager %}
```

This will check is that profile object's manager property is `True`

Comment: I tried but I does not work either. 

{% if profile.manager %}
  Manager
{% else %}
Not manager
{% endif %}

Not matter what, "no manager" is shown

Comment: Yes I have checked the box on my profile, but even with your other answer I does not change on wether I set it to true or false

Comment: I have added my full model.py

Answer (score 0):

If you have not overridden your view `context` you need to access your fields with `object`.

```
{% if object.manager %}
    SHOW THE CONTENT
{%else%}
    Does not show the content
{% endif %}
```